# kubectl create secret via gitlab throwing error

Tags: gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-secrets

I am using gitlab CI/CD and GKE. I am trying to create a secret via gitlab. I am getting error like below

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Below is the code in yaml file.

```
deploy to dev:
  stage: Dev-Deploy
  image: dtzar/helm-kubectl
  script:
    - kubectl create secret docker-registry  pradeep_secret --docker-server=$ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REPOSITORY --docker-username=$ARTIFACTORY_USER --docker-password=$ARTIFACTORY_PASS --docker-email="abc@gmail.com"
```

How do i go about debugging or fixing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you didn't configure correctly the configuration of the cluster.
You can run `kubectl config view` to view the current configuration used by the CI, and ensure it's correct.

The error means that the CI is trying to connect to a cluster listening on `http://localhost:8080`, and this cluster does not answer. I guess this is not a correct config - which explain why it doesn't work. This is the default configuration used in case no configuration supplied.

Comment: My cluster in on GKE.

Comment: Did you configured kubectl so it will point the cluster? The [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) explains how.

Comment: I got the issue. I was using the above command before mapping the cluster.